# Redis Cluster: Replace failing master that has no slave without downtime

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am looking into using Redis Cluster (Redis 4.0).

I have a cluster of 5 master nodes, each with one replica. We can call each master `A, B, C, D, E` respectively, and each slave `A1, B1, C1, D1, E1`.

**Say, for example, that a node fills up its memory and causes master B and slave B1 to both fail. Is there any way to recover from this state?**

**Ideally I would like to be able to spin up a new node, load it with an RDB backup of B, join it into the cluster, and reallocate B's slots to the replacement node without having to bring the rest of the cluster down.**

I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resume hash slots of a particular node in redis cluster in case of hard failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416199/how-to-resume-hash-slots-of-a-particular-node-in-redis-cluster-in-case-of-hard-f)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to **create more replicas on different nodes** than that of master. In such a scenario as listed above you will still have your backup in some replica(on another node).

And also using this there will be no need to load RDB backup in a new node or to join it into the cluster or to reallocate B's slots to the replacement node without having to bring the rest of the cluster down.

You can do all this simply by using **Redis Sentinel** : https://redis.io/topics/sentinel